# Cant understand the implementation of max function in the linux kernel

Tags: linux, c

What's the significance of (void) (&_max1 == &_max2); in the following definition of max found in Linux/tools/lib/lockdep/uinclude/linux/kernel.h?

```
#define max(x, y) ({                            \
      typeof(x) _max1 = (x);                  \
      typeof(y) _max2 = (y);                  \
      (void) (&_max1 == &_max2);              \
      _max1 > _max2 ? _max1 : _max2; })
```

Comment: It is a compile time type-check. Optimized out in compiled code.

Comment: @Sukminder it might be useful to explain the purpose of the check

Answer (score 1):

It helps the compiler detect invalid uses of `max()`, *i.e.* with non-comparable `x` and `y`. As [Sukminder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/28489/sukminder) points out, the `==` check is only used at compile time, it doesn't end up in the resulting binary.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how checking for equality of addresses of 2 variables amounts to checking types?